# When and why do we overload operators in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++  and my questions are: Why do we need to overload operators in C++ and when should we overload operators in C++, why don't we just use built-in variables to do calculations, comparison, output and input value. I just don't get it, what is the most appropriate situation where we would need to overload operators or should we always overload operators when dealing with classes?

Comment: What if you want to use `+` on complex numbers that you implemented?

Comment: As an example, what if you make a class named `Color`. If I ask you, what `Color` is produced by `Color('Red') + Color('Yellow')`, you would say `Color('Orange')`, correct? Obviously a color isn't a C++ primitive, but you could define what the `+` operator means. There are infinite other situations when this type of problem pops up.

Comment: In brief, whenever the resultant syntax would make sense for the type being used (e.g. a mathematical type or smart pointer). Be careful of the "tricks" and cute code, inevitably that makes it harder to maintain in the long run.

Comment: @Cyber. Why don't you just define two Strings instead of a class? Sorry if I don't follow but I'm relatively new to programming.

Comment: Because `std::string` already has a `+` operator. If you had to add two strings, then `'Red' + 'Yellow' = 'RedYellow'` not `'Orange'`. Plus `Color` could do many other things that don't make sense with strings, like `lighten`, `saturate`, `greyscale`, etc. These would all be methods that only make sense for a given class.

Comment: Not a dupe of the indicated question.  This question asks "why," whereas that question answers "how."

Comment: Usually you should not overload operators as day-to-day code gets unreadable very fast. On the other hand every class will provide a default implementation of operator= for assignment, which you should be aware of, and it's good practice to either make this operator explicit (to encourage its use or if you need to handle dynamic memory) or to make it private if assignment is not something your objects support. As with other operators: they are simply functions, functions with special syntax (infix, postfix, prefix) and ordering (^ before * before + before =, etc...) use them where appropriate!

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you all for you help, I now completely understand. Thanks to all of those who answered.

Comment: The most important reason i can think of is that you need operator== implemented in your Class in order to run std::find on a container of Class objects. I rarely implement other operators to be honest, but that's probably just my bad habit.

Comment: @Martin If the reason is just to use `std::find`, rather than `std::find_if`, that's practically obfuscation.  If the notion of equality is well defined for the object, however, you should implement both `==` and `!=`.  (You should never implement one without implementing the other.)

Comment: Sometime, have a look at Boost spirit (www.boost.org). That's a real touchstone for appropriate operator overloading.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at a lot of C++ sources, you'd probably conclude
that the most frequent use of operator overloading (or
overloading in general, for that matter) is obfuscation.
Still...

First and foremost: in a number of cases, you'll have to
overload the assignment operator.  The compiler will generate
one for you if you don't, and in a number of cases, the
generated one won't do what you want.  (It's also frequent to
declare a private overloaded assignment, and not implement it,
in order to block assignment.)

If a class represents some sort of numerical value (e.g.
`BigInteger` or `Decimal`), then it definitely makes sense to
overload the arithmetic operators.  It's a lot more readable to
write:

```
BigFloat
discriminant( BigFloat const& a, BigFloat const& b, BigFloat const& c )
{
    return b*b - 4*a*c
}
```

than

```
BigFloat
discriminant( BigFloat const& a, BigFloat const& b, BigFloat const& c )
{
    return sub(mult(b, b), mult(4, mult( a, c )));
}
```

In such cases, you should always overload *all* applicable
operators, with their natural meanings: it would be very uncool
if your type supported `+`, but not `+=`, or if it supported `+`
with the semantics of subtraction.

There are few legitimate extensions with regards to the
arithmetic operators: about the only one I'd find acceptable is
a string class using `+` (and `+=`) for concatenation.
(Normally, I'd expect `+` to be commutative, which concatenation
certainly isn't.  But the convention is so well established in
languages that have built-in string types that you can hardly
avoid it.)

Types that are comparable should support `==` and `!=`, and if
there is a logical ordering, `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=`.  (On the
other hand, overloading `<` when there is only an arbitrary
ordering, just so you can call `std::sort` without an comparison
operator, is obfuscation.)  Again, it's much more natural to
write `a < b` than `isLessThan( a, b )`.  It's sometimes
difficult to decide: when I first started C++, I had a `Set`
class, based on bitmaps, and I defined `<` to be a strict
subset, `<=` a subset, etc.  I don't know if I'd do this again;
the inequality operators should probably only be defined if the
relationship is transitive.

Beyond that, any time your type emulates in some way something
built in, like a pointer or an array, you will probably want to
overload the corresponding supported operators: a vector or an
array class which didn't support `[]` would be surprizing, as
would be a smart pointer which didn't support `*` and `->`.

And finally, there are some standard C++ idioms which use
operator overloading:

- If you define a type which can be inserted or extracted from a text stream, you do so by defining the `<<` and `>>` operators.
- C++ iterators are designed to look like pointers; if you want
  iterators which can be used with the standard algorithms, they
  should support the same operators as those of a smart pointer,
  along with `++`, and possibly `--`, and in some cases, all of
  the pointer arithmetic operators (including `[]`, which is
  defined in terms of pointer arithmetic on raw pointers).  This
  is clearly obfuscation, and it certainly makes using the
  iterators unnecessarily complicated, but it's hard to avoid if
  you're using the C++ standard library.
- The C++ library also makes extensive use of functional
  objects, with an `operator()` (a function call operator).
  Predicate objects have an `operator()` which returns a `bool`.
  (One of the most frequent uses of predicate objects is to
  implement an ordering relationship.  If your class doesn't
  support a logical `<` operator, you might want to provide
  a separate functional object which defines an arbitrary order,
  so that objects can still be inserted into `std::set`, or be
  used as a key in `std::map`.) Arguably, this too should have
  been a named function, but it's hard to imagine a good name that
  would apply everywhere, and since the object does behave like
  a function, it's not really too bad.

There are probably one or two other cases I've forgotten, but in
general, with regards to operator overloading, when in doubt,
don't.

Comment: I'd have concluded the the most frequent use of operator overloading would have been assignation, even if it's the default one.

Comment: +1 but it might be worth mentioning `<<` and `>>` from STL streams (assuming you find them acceptable too).

Comment: @Geoffroy Yes.  That one is so usual, it didn't occur to me to mention it, but it's true.

Comment: @YogiBear Agreed.  In C++, `<<` and `>>` are the insertion and extraction operators (which are abusively overloaded for shifting on the integral types:-)).